# How much faster are airmolecules going when the temperature raise from 15 to 25 degrees C?

Tags: homework-and-exercises, thermodynamics, temperature, kinetic-theory

As far as I know the temperature of the air depends on how fast the airmolecules are moving. But what is the increase of speed (in km/h) of those air molecules?

Comment: The energy of a molecule follows the equi-partition theorem, $E = n k_B T$ where n is degrees of freedom of the molecules. This can then be placed into the formula for kinetic energy $E = \frac{1}{2} m v^2$. Solving for the difference of the velocities at two different temperatures gets you your answer.

Comment: $<v^2> \alpha T$, where $T$ is the absolute temperature, so you need to convert $T (^O C)$ to $T (K)$.

Comment: Should find for air (remember air is a mixture of gases) at room temperature ($20^0 C$), $\sqrt{<v^2>} \approx 500 m/s$

Answer (score 4):

Looking [around](https://uk.answers.yahoo.com/question/index?qid=20091214203438AAcaEte), the root mean square speed of air at $20$ C is about $500 m/s$, and given that you have $\langle v^2 \rangle \propto \, T$ so that $v_{rms}(T) = \sqrt{\langle v^2\rangle}$ varies with $\sqrt{T}$ then have
$$v_{rms}(15) = v_{rms}(20)\times \frac{\sqrt{15+273}}{\sqrt{20+273}} \approx 496 m/s$$
and
$$v_{rms}(25) = v_{rms}(20)\times \frac{\sqrt{25+273}}{\sqrt{20+273}} \approx 504 m/s$$

Comment: 1785 km/h - 1814 = 29 km/h. So a temperature raise of 10 degrees has an increase of speed of 29km/h or 1,6%. That is not a very big difference comparing to what we feel.

Comment: People are good at noticing temperature changes.

Answer (score 0):

The [*speed of sound*](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Speed_of_sound), which is effectively a measure of how fast particles are moving on average in a gas, is given by:
$$
C_{s}^{2} = \frac{\partial P}{\partial \rho} \tag{1}
$$
where $P$ is the pressure and $\rho$ is the mass density.  For an [ideal gas](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ideal_gas), one can use an adiabatic [equation of state](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Equation_of_state) such that Equation 1 goes to:
$$
C_{s}^{2} = \frac{ \gamma \ P }{ \rho } \tag{2}
$$
where $\gamma$ is the [adiabatic or polytrope index](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Heat_capacity_ratio) of the gas.  For a monatomic ideal gas, one can use $\gamma = 5/3$ and the [ideal gas law](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ideal_gas_law) for pressure.  Then Equation 2 goes to:
$$
\begin{align}
C_{s}^{2} & = \frac{ \gamma \ n \ k_{B} \ T }{ \rho } \tag{3a} \\
& = \frac{ \gamma \ k_{B} \ T }{ m } \tag{3b} \\
& = \frac{ \gamma \ R \ T }{ M } \tag{3c}
\end{align}
$$
where $n$ is the number density, $k_{B}$ is [Boltzmann's constant](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Boltzmann_constant), $R$ is the [gas constant](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gas_constant), $T$ is the average [temperature](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Temperature), $m$ is the particle mass, and $M$ is the molar mass of the gas.

The [Earth's atmosphere](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Atmosphere_of_Earth) at sea level has a molar mass of [~28.9645 g $mol^{-1}$](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Density_of_air), $R = 8.3144598(48) \ J \ K^{-1} \ mol^{-1}$, we chose $\gamma = 5/3$ (or we could use 7/5 for a diatomic molecule, but it's just a constant), and now we choose temperatures.

The constant factors in front are roughly equal to:
$$
\sqrt{\frac{ \gamma \ R }{ M }} \sim 21.873
$$
so that we can say the speed of sound goes as:
$$
C_{s} \sim 21.873 \ \sqrt{T} \tag{4}
$$
Then for we choose a bunch of temperatures and calculate the corresponding speeds of sound, which are shown in the table below.

```
Temperature [K] | Temperature [deg C] | Speed [m/s] | Speed [km/h] 
-------------------------------------------------------------------
  100.00        |       -173.15       |    218.73   |     878.4    
  225.00        |        -48.15       |    328.10   |    1181.2    
  273.15        |          0.00       |    361.50   |    1301.4    
  288.15        |         15.00       |    371.29   |    1336.6    
  298.15        |         25.00       |    377.68   |    1359.6    
  625.00        |        351.85       |    546.83   |    1968.6    
  900.00        |        626.85       |    656.19   |    2362.3    
  2500.0        |       2226.85       |   1093.65   |    3937.1
```

Note that if we had used $\gamma = 7/5$, the speeds would have changed by a factor of ~0.92 (i.e., decreased by roughly 8%).